# Saving entity using crudrepository taking too much time

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to update an entry in the DB using crudrepository but its taking ~ 24 seconds for each iteration. Below is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
for(tmp.request.Number numb : Num_list){
            EnterpriseVnumbList addNumb = entNumbdao.findByVnumbmsisdnAndEnterpriseid(numb.getNumber(), frmEntp);

            if(addNumb != null){

                addNumb.setEnterpriseId(toEntp);                     // toEnt is a class Enterprise
                entNumbdao.save(addNumb); // entNumbdao is EnterpriseVnumbListRepo 
                addEntpToEnt++;
            }else{
                log.error("NumbProcessing: Failed to");              
            }
```

Here is my EnterpriseVnumbList class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enterprise_vnumb_list", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"vnumb_msisdn"})})
@XmlRootElement
public class EnterpriseVnumbList implements Serializable {
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private String parentId;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "vnumb_msisdn", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String vnumbmsisdn;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "imsi", length = 30)
    private String imsi;
    @Column(name = "assigned")
    private Boolean assigned;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "assigned_to_sim", length = 30)
    private String assignedtosim;
    @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id", referencedColumnName = "enterprise_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Enterprise enterpriseid;
/// Some code here
}
```

// Here is EnterpriseVnumbListRepo class

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass=EnterpriseVnumbList.class, idClass=Integer.class)    
public interface EnterpriseVnumbListRepo extends CrudRepository<EnterpriseVnumbList, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<EnterpriseVnumbList>{
    EnterpriseVnumbList findByVnumbmsisdnAndEnterpriseidAndAssigned(String vsim, Enterprise enterpriseid, boolean assgn);
    EnterpriseVnumbList findByVnumbmsisdnAndEnterpriseid(String vsim, Enterprise enterpriseid);
    List<EnterpriseVnumbList> findByEnterpriseidAndAssigned(Enterprise entp, boolean assgn);
    EnterpriseVnumbList findByVnumbmsisdnAndAssignedtosim(String vsim, String sim);
    EnterpriseVnumbList findByVnumbmsisdnAndEnterpriseidAndAssignedNot(String vsim, Enterprise enterpriseid, boolean assgn);
    Long countByEnterpriseidAndAssigned(Enterprise entp, boolean assgn);
    Long countByEnterpriseid(Enterprise entp);
}
```

Comment: I would check the query which is issued ty this statement : EnterpriseVnumbList addNumb = entNumbdao.findByVnumbmsisdnAndEnterpriseid(numb.getNumber(), frmEntp); Does it take as long when you execute it directly on the database via sql ?

Comment: findByVnumbmsisdnAndEnterpriseid does not take any time. Its executed instantly. Only entNumbdao.save(addNumb) takes time.